# Remove = sign before number when using siunitx round-minimum

Tags: siunitx

I am creating macros to format p values using siunitx. I want them to round to three decimal places, with anything below 0.001 given as <0.001.
This works fine when printing a p value by itself, but when printing it in text it gives p=<0.001.
How do I set it so that it does not print the = sign if round-minimum triggers and it prints the < sign?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\pvalue}[1]{%
    \num[round-mode=places, round-precision=3, round-minimum=0.001]{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\pequals}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{p=\pvalue{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\pvalue{0.0003}\\
\pequals{0.0123}\\
\pequals{0.0003}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can compare the value with 0.001 before `\num` does its job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pequals}{m}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 < 0.001 }
   {
    \ensuremath{ p < \num{0.001} }
   }
   {
    \ensuremath{ p = \num[round-mode=places, round-precision=3]{#1} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pequals{0.0123}  

\pequals{0.0003}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A fancier version, where you can add options to `pequals`: `min` states the threshold under which a number is simply printed with < *n*; other options are passed to `sisetup`, so they should be meaningful for `\num`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pequals}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { pyrrhic/pequals }
   {
    min=0.001,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3,
    #1
   }
  \fp_compare:nTF { #2 < \l_pyrrhic_pequals_min_fp }
   {
    \ensuremath{ p < \num{\fp_use:N \l_pyrrhic_pequals_min_fp} }
   }
   {
    \ensuremath{ p = \num{#2} }
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\keys_define:nn { pyrrhic/pequals }
 {
  min .fp_set:N = \l_pyrrhic_pequals_min_fp,
  unknown .code:n = \use:x { \sisetup { \l_keys_key_tl = \exp_not:n { #1 } } },
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pequals{0.0123}

\pequals{0.0003}

\pequals[min=0.0001,round-precision=4]{0.0003}

\pequals[min=0.0001,round-precision=4]{0.00003}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Note that with `round-minimum=0.001`, there is no space between `<` and `0.001`. In addition, `\num` (which is used inside `\pequals`) outputs `<0.001` only if its argument is actually less than `0.0005`, not `0.001`. (This is because rounding has been enabled via the option `round-mode=places`; check the output of `\pequals` for `0.00051` and `0.00049` to verify this claim.) This outcome may well run counter to common expectations that (IMNSHO) that the `<0.001` string should be generated whenever the argument of `\num` is less than `0.001`, not whenever it's less than `0.0005`. For sure, this is what you appear to expect, as you wrote that one of your objectives was

> with anything below 0.001 given as <0.001.

In order to get the spacing around the `<` symbol to be the same around the `=` symbol, and in order to ensure that the cutoff `<0.001` means what readers are entitled to think it means, it's best to write the routine from scratch. The following example shows how this may be done by using LuaLaTeX. The left-hand column shows the output of the new macro, called `\ptest`, and the right-hand column shows the output of `\pequals`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function ptest ( i )
   if i<0.001 then
      tex.sprint ( "\\ensuremath{p<0.001}" )
   else
      tex.sprint ( "\\ensuremath{p="..string.format("%.3f",i).."}" )
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\ptest[1]{\directlua{ptest(#1)}}

%% The OP's code for '\pvalue' and '\pequals':
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\pvalue}[1]{\num[round-mode=places, 
         round-precision=3, round-minimum=0.001]{#1}}
\newcommand{\pequals}[1]{\ensuremath{p=\pvalue{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\ptest{0.3456},  \pequals{0.3456}

\ptest{0.0123},  \pequals{0.0123}

\ptest{0.00101}, \pequals{0.00101}

\ptest{0.00098}, \pequals{0.00098}

\ptest{0.00049}, \pequals{0.00049}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the reason something like 0.0005 doesn't give the 'less than' value is that it _rounds_ to 0.001: it's that which is tested.

Comment: @JosephWright - Thanks for this clarification. Is there an option to skip rounding before the `<0.001` test is applied to the argument of `\num`?